# Irish naturalisation as British citizen?

Tags: ireland, naturalization

Reading about the [Common Travel Area](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/common-travel-area-guidance/common-travel-area-guidance), it looks like I, as a British citizen, can live and work in Ireland without restrictions. What I can't see is whether this can eventually lead to naturalisation in Ireland, or whether there are any restrictions in this area?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What I can't see is whether this can eventually lead to naturalisation in Ireland

It can

> or whether there are any restrictions in this area?

There are.  See the Irish government's page [Becoming an Irish citizen through naturalisation](https://www.gov.ie/en/service/4b84e-becoming-an-irish-citizen-through-naturalisation/):

> ## What Naturalisation is
>
> A foreign national living in Ireland who meets certain standards may apply to become a "naturalised" Irish citizen. To apply, you must have been physically resident in Ireland for a certain length of time.
>
> ## Qualifying
>
> The conditions for Naturalisation were set out in the Irish Nationality and Citizenship Act 1956 as amended. These are:
>
> ### Age
>
> You must be over 18.
>
> You can apply on behalf of a child if
>
> - the child was born in Ireland after 1 January 2005 and did not qualify for citizenship by birth – use Form 11 on the INIS website
> - the child is of Irish descent – use Form 10 on the INIS website
> - the parent is a naturalised citizen – use Form 9 on the INIS website
>
> ### Character
>
> You must be ‘of good character.’ To prove this, you must ask the Garda Síochána for a report about your background.
>
> ### Residence in the State
>
> You must have lived in the State for a certain length of time. You must:
>
> - have a period of 365 days* (1 year) continuous residence in the State immediately before the date of your application for naturalisation
> - have spent 1,460 day, or 4 years, in the State in the 8 years before that
>
> You must have spent 5 of the past 9 years in residence in Ireland.
>
> You can spend up to 6 weeks per year outside of Ireland and still be considered a resident. If you had to leave Ireland for longer than 6 weeks because of an emergency, you should explain this in your application.
>
> If you spend more than 6 weeks outside of Ireland in the year immediately before your application, you may have to wait until the following year to make an application.
>
> ## Apply
>
> To apply, you must use the most up-to-date versions of the application forms on the Immigration Service Delivery website.
>
> There is an application fee of €175. If you are successful, there may be an additional fee of up to €950.